# Changing element style using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change a spans style using JavaScript but cannot seem to do it. Below I have created the span and given it an Id "spanzo", then I have stored the span in a var "elementtl" and tried two ways to add styles to it but its not doing anything. Styles have already been set to the span, I am just trying to override them styles.

```
const letterEl = document.createElement("span");
    letterEl.setAttribute("id", "spanzo");

var elementtl = document.getElementById("spanzo");
    elementtl.classList.toggle("spanzo1");
    elementtl.style.backgroundColor = "red"; 


#spanzo{
transform: rotatey(0deg);
}
.spanzo1{
transform: rotatey(180deg);
transition: 2s;
}
```

Comment: you need to add `letterEl` to DOM

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly How do I do that?

Comment: `document.body.appendChild(letterEl)`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly and where should I put this?, the span is created in another file and I am trying to add styles in a different file

Answer (score 0):

```js
const letterEl = document.createElement("span");
letterEl.innerText = "This is a span.";
document.body.appendChild(letterEl);
    letterEl.setAttribute("id", "spanzo");

var elementtl = document.getElementById("spanzo");
    elementtl.classList.toggle("spanzo1");
    elementtl.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

```css
#spanzo{
transform: rotatey(0deg);
}
.spanzo1{
transform: rotatey(180deg);
transition: 2s;
}
```

Comment: I have created the span in another file and I am trying to add a style in a different file, would this could still work if it is split up between files?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const letterEl = document.createElement("span");
    letterEl.setAttribute("id", "spanzo");
    letterEl.textContent = 'hello world';
    document.body.appendChild(letterEl);


var elementtl = document.getElementById("spanzo");
    elementtl.classList.toggle("spanzo1");
    elementtl.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

```css
#spanzo{
transform: rotatey(0deg);
}
.spanzo1{
transform: rotatey(180deg);
transition: 2s;
}
```

Comment: I have created the span in another file and I am trying to add a style in a different file, would this could still work if it is split up between files?

Comment: yes it will work

Comment: do i put appendChild code with the file that created the span or with the code i am trying to add styles to the span?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add a width and height to your #spanzo style for it to actually occupy some space and you need to add it to the `<body>` element using

```
document.body.append(letterEl)
```

All together

```
const letterEl = document.createElement("span");
    letterEl.setAttribute("id", "spanzo");
    
  document.body.append(letterEl)  
document.body.appendChild(letterEl);

var elementtl = document.getElementById("spanzo");
    elementtl.classList.toggle("spanzo1");
    elementtl.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

```
#spanzo{
transform: rotatey(0deg);
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
.spanzo1{
transform: rotatey(180deg);
transition: 2s;
}
```

Comment: The span already has styles added to it, im just trying to override them styles with new ones, so when a function is true then the new styles will be added

Answer (score 0):

To create and append an element you may want to use `insertAdjacentHTML`. To add or remove css-classes use `classList[add/remove]`. For example:

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, 
  `<div id="spanzo">Hi, i am div#spanzo</div>`);
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function demo() {
  const demoElem = document.querySelector(`#spanzo`);
  demoElem.textContent = `Hi, i am div#spanzo. Wait a sec ...`;
  setTimeout(() => {
    demoElem.classList.add(`spanzo1`);
    setTimeout(() => {
      demoElem.classList.remove(`spanzo1`);
      demoElem.textContent = `I'm back!`}, 3000);
    }, 1000);
}
  
function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.nodeName === `BUTTON`) {
    return demo();
  }
}
```

```css
#spanzo.spanzo1{
  transform: rotatey(180deg);
  transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<button>Demo</button>
```